# AWS MQ parse with queue or lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, activemq-classic

Let's say I place 1000 small xml files on an aws mq queue and want to transform all of them to json before deliver to another system. 
Can you extend the broker queue and say write java code, or do I need a subscriber lambda and a worker lambda for that?

I was planning on using the pattern describen in this blog post,
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/invoking-aws-lambda-from-amazon-mq/

Answer (score 0):

The approach described in the document uses a Lambda function which periodically looks for messages in AWS MQ and forward them to be processed by delegating them to a worker Lambda functions ( Where many can process in parallel).

Therefore you need to place your Java code in the worker Lambda function for the JSON transformation.

Comment: I was under the impression you could write plugins for the AWS MQ-queue, but ok then I need to place the transformation in a worker Lambda. Can the queue trigger the working lambda directly? As soon as I place one xml, the lambda is directly started?